# search sql query

Tags: php, sql

I was working on my college project and found really interesting.

I wanted to know how search engine's algo is build up as it corrects the spelling mistakes too.

I want to implement same thing.

For example I have three things to be searched name,email and phone.

If one of the user name is john miller and I search john miler it should show up results even for Jon miler. Similarly for email john@gmaiw.com should show up john@gmail.com

I wanted to know is this possible ??? And what will be its algo. Like query doesn't seems to be good for the same.

Comment: others implemented [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Comment: @JW. U know abt Levenshtein distance?? Can you explain it??

Comment: Please explain how to implement

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL? Oracle? DB2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are looking for like statement of SQL, please go through following link - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html